# How to validate a dropdown menu in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Web Design and I did not find a suitable answer for my question in the community. I need to validate a dropdown menu with JavaScript and the button `btn1` but my code doesn't work, I'll just include a snippet for simplicity sake. Please help

```
<form>
<label for="dropdown1">Option</label>
        <select id="dropdown1">
            <option value="">--Select an option--</option>
            <option value="option1">1</option>
            <option value="option2">2</option>
        </select>
</form>
 <button type="button" id="btn1" required>Calcular</button>
```

Here is my js

```
btn1.addEventListener('click', validate(dropdown1.value))
let dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
function validate(object) {

    if (object.value == "") {

        alert("Select an option")
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', validate(object))
```

Comment: Learn about the difference between function invocations and function references. Your event callback expects a callback, i.e. a function reference - but you're invoking the function in situ. The result is the function is called when you bind the event, not when it fires.

Comment: Use change event in place of click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting up an event listener you can either pass it the function name or write an inline function. The problem you were running into was trying to pass it a name and an argument at once. Also you can determine the dropdown element's value in the callback without worrying about passing it in.

```js
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
const dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
btn1.addEventListener('click', validate);

function validate() {
  const dropdownValue = dropdown1.value;
  if (dropdownValue == "") {

  alert("Select an option")
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label for="dropdown1">Option</label>
        <select id="dropdown1">
            <option value="">--Select an option--</option>
            <option value="option1">1</option>
            <option value="option2">2</option>
        </select>
</form>
 <button type="button" id="btn1" required>Calcular</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much, I understand now. You helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!